# Asp.net MVC using the same controller for multiple routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a simple controller like this (no, not really, but let's say I do)

```
public class SomethingController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Method1() {
        return View("Something1");
    }

    public ActionResult Method2() {
        return View("Something2");
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this controller with two different routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.MapRoute("Route 1", "Route1/{action}", new { controller = "Something" });
    routes.MapRoute("Route 2", "Route2/{action}", new { controller = "Something" });
}
```

Up until here, nothing special. However, inside my view `Something1` I now want to do do

```
Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "Method2")
```

and this should render `<a href="Route1/Method2"...` or `<a href="Route2/Method2"...`, depending on which route led to the controller that displayed the view. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Html.RouteLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink`. It lets you specify the route name.

Comment: @Obalix: Really? How would that work? I thought it would then only find a controller with the name Route1Controller. Can you elaborate?